# Split Screen in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a way (plugin or something) to use split screen in the Atom Editor?

I've looked inside the menus, but I can't find any related options.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found this at [Split Windows - issue #64](https://github.com/atom/vim-mode/issues/64):

> It seems like Atom already has support for splitting windows (cmd-k + arrow key)

Comment: ctrl+K + arrow key where you want the next pane to be for windows

Answer (score 166):

### Using the command palette

Open the command palette with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (OSX) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (Linux/Windows) and type "split". You'll see options for Up, Down, Left, and Right split.

### Using keyboard shortcuts

Split the current tab in a direction with the following shortcuts

- Up       <kbd>cmd / ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>↑</kbd>
- Down  <kbd>cmd / ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>↓</kbd>
- Left     <kbd>cmd / ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>←</kbd>
- Right   <kbd>cmd / ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>→</kbd>

You can close an active split pane with <kbd>cmd / ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>cmd / ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>.

### Move between panes

If you want to move between open panes (with the keyboard) you have to modify your keymap file. Go to *Atom -> Open Your Keymap* and include this:

```
'body':
  'cmd-alt left': 'window:focus-pane-on-left'
  'cmd-alt right': 'window:focus-pane-on-right'
  'cmd-alt up': 'window:focus-pane-above'
  'cmd-alt down': 'window:focus-pane-below'
  'cmd-alt-2': 'pane:split-right'
  'cmd-alt-3': 'pane:split-down'
```

This is my personal setup. I was used to Sublime's default `cmd + alt + arrow`. Change the left side commands to your personal preference.

#### Note

You need to press `cmd-alt` once, release, and then press the arrow button. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I switch between frames?

Comment: @Moriss, I was wondering that too. Found out: `ctrl` + `k`, then `ctrl` + `<arrrow>`. Or, just `ctrl + k + <arrow>`.

Comment: Should it not be `cmd-alt-left` instead of `cmd-alt left`? I tried yours and it didn't work but then I added the dash and it worked.

Comment: @norbertpy you're right. I don't know how I managed to copy and paste it wrong lol. I'll update the answer as well. thanks

Comment: @norbertpy actually, I was right. If you add the dash you cannot move between opened files anymore. You can only switch panes. If you leave a space between, you have the ability to switch panes and move between files, but you need to do it in 2 steps. Hit `cmd-alt` "leave" your fingers from keyboard and then press an arrow.

Comment: Any ideas on how to troubleshoot if this is not working?  Ctrl+k works locally in other applications, so I don't think there's any global hijacking going on.  I see the options in the command palette, but the key combinations don't work.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as Shane. Cmd-K Cmd-left (right/up/down) isn't working for me either. I'm not sure quite what to do.

Comment: How do you know to put these under `'body'`, and not `'atom-text-editor'` or `'atom-workspace'` etc?

Comment: I wish to edit "at a glance " a long tex file... any way to synchronize scrolling for panes?

Answer (score 23):

Right click anywhere on an open file, select "split left"

[image]

If it duplicates a file, "x" it out.

---

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I have created a beginners cheat sheet for Atom that lists some introductory notes and keyboard shortcut commands etc. Its on github @ 
https://github.com/pd-gmit/atom-cheatsheet/blob/master/atom_cheatsheet.md

Comment: Do you know how to display a pane in a new window ?

Answer (score 8):

You could always just right click anywhere on the file and the split options are available in the context menu.

Comment: The idea behind having keyboard shortcuts is to improve your productivity and reduce hand/wrist/arm movement. The fact that you have to move your hand away from the keyboard to right click on your mouse is quite inefficient.

Comment: The question was not for a short cut, so I don't know why you would leave such a comment to state such an obvious fact.

Comment: You are entirely right and I apologise for the out of context comment. I guess I got carried away with the long answer teaching how to use the keyboard shortcuts. Nevertheless, if one considers SO as a teaching platform, then we should try to instil good ideas.